# How do I make a top-docked control appear *under* the existing top-docked controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, docking

I am dynamically adding controls to my form with `Dock = DockStyle.Top`.  I want subsequent controls to appear below the existing ones.  By default, each new control added goes to the top.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit:  I am adding these controls at run time, not design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It never fails.  I just discovered an answer myself, but for anyone else who finds this question later, the answer was to call `.SetChildIndex(ctrl, 0)` on the container.